# How to initiate and assign values to a nested dictionary dynamically

Tags: python

I am attempting to dynamically initiate and assign values to a nested dictionary in Python, I have been unsuccessful so far, Kindly help me out, thank you.
This is what I have attempted.

```
thelist = [
['2023', 'John Professa', 'Mfangano', '10 E', '84 A', '84 A', '3 E', '53 C', '65 B', '84 A', '84 A', '84 A', '84 A', '84 A', '400', 464, '66', '64', 'B', '1'],
['33332', 'd dd', 'Mfangano', '40 D+', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '403', 40, '6', '4', 'E', '5'],
['3333', 'Isaac ', 'Mfangano', '83 A', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '402', 83, '12', '12', 'D-', '2'],
['1234', 'asdfas f', 'Mfangano', '60 B-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '390', 60, '9', '8', 'E', '4'],
['7777', 'asdfas f', 'Kujeni', '66 B', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '280', 66, '9', '9', 'E', '3'],
]

nested_Dictionary = {}

main_dorms = ['kujeni', 'Mfangano', 'Bakini', 'Kujeni', 'Flamingo']

for value in main_dorms:
    nested_Dictionary[f'{value}'] = {}
    nested_Dictionary[f'{value}']['A'] = [1]
    nested_Dictionary[f'{value}']['A-'] = [1]
    nested_Dictionary[f'{value}']['B+'] = [1]
    nested_Dictionary[f'{value}']['B-'] = [1]
    nested_Dictionary[f'{value}']['C+'] = [1]
    nested_Dictionary[f'{value}']['C'] = [1]
    nested_Dictionary[f'{value}']['C-'] = [1]
    nested_Dictionary[f'{value}']['D+'] = [1]
    nested_Dictionary[f'{value}']['D'] = [1]
    nested_Dictionary[f'{value}']['D-'] = [1]
    nested_Dictionary[f'{value}']['E'] = [1]
    nested_Dictionary[f'{value}']['mean'] = [1]
    nested_Dictionary[f'{value}']['meangrade'] = [1]

print(nested_Dictionary)

for value in thelist:
    idnumber = value[0]
    stream = value[2]
    meangrade = value[18]
    meanmarks = value[17]

    print(idnumber, stream, meangrade, meanmarks)
    nested_Dictionary[f'{stream}'][meangrade].append(meangrade)
    nested_Dictionary[f'{stream}']['mean'].append(meanmarks)
    nested_Dictionary[f'{stream}']['meangrade'].append(meanmarks)

print(nested_Dictionary)
```

This gives me a key error

```
 nested_Dictionary[f'{stream}'][meangrade].append(meangrade)
KeyError: 'Mfangano'
```

Comment: FWIW, `f'{value}'` is very superfluous, just `value` will do exactly the same thing…

Comment: Why do you use `f'{value}'` for a key? Why not `nested_Dictionary[value]` ?

Comment: I get `KeyError: 'B'`.

Comment: If I run this, I get `KeyError: 'B'` which makes sense as `'B'` is missing from your inner keys.

Comment: I tried your code and did not get your specific `KeyError`, instead I got `*** KeyError: 'B'`. Either way, the issue is that you need to check if the dictionary contains a key before you try to index it with a specific key. Take a look at https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

Comment: So you might do: 
`try: \
    dict[Index]  \
except KeyError: \
    pass`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should re-approach this using something that lets you dynamically build a jagged dictionary - it'll be *way* more extensible.  My preferred implementation is this:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> 
>>> def defaulter():
...   return defaultdict(defaulter)
... 
>>> nested = defaultdict(defaulter)
>>> nested['a'][1]['c'][None] = True
>>> nested
defaultdict(<function defaulter at 0x7ffb8ba6db80>, {'a': defaultdict(<function defaulter at 0x7ffb8ba6db80>, {1: defaultdict(<function defaulter at 0x7ffb8ba6db80>, {'c': defaultdict(<function defaulter at 0x7ffb8ba6db80>, {None: True})})})})
```

You'll never run into KeyErrors when assigning.  The caveat is that you also won't run into KeyErrors when accessing missing values, regardless how nested, and it will produce empty `defaultdict`'s down the tree:

```
>>> nested['missing']
defaultdict(<function defaulter at 0x7ffb8ba6db80>, {})
```

Answer (score 2):

Add to your for loop:

```
nested_Dictionary[f'{value}']['B'] = [1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the quotes around meangrade, your code worked when I added this.

```
 nested_Dictionary[f'{stream}']['meangrade'].append(meangrade)
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is intended behavior? `meangrade` contains `'B'` which seems to be a possible key of `nested_Dictionary[f'{stream}']`. But without OP clarifying on what he wants the code to do I suppose we cannot know